# MVC 4 with jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a jquery tab in mvc project using the code below, and it doesnt work. Please advice what am i missing? I am using the sample code from [jqueryui site](http://jqueryui.com)

the view:

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    $(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
</script>


 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Register</a></li>        
  </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
    @Html.Partial("_login")
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
    @Html.Partial("_register")
 </div>
```

I also have two links in my layout "login" and "register" links how can I manage so when login link is clicked display tabs-1 and when register link is clicked display tabs-2

when I run the code, the output result, doesnt work:

[image]

thank you

Comment: @Satpal please see updated question, updated with the result it shows

Comment: you should give scripts url like this:
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")"></script>

Comment: I closed the tag, and added the new format to get the scripts and still not working.

Comment: @Ben, Are you getting any error in console? For reference [Debugging JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging)

Comment: @Satpal you right I get error below  Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' and GET http://localhost:61083/images/Brand-logo.png 404 (Not Found) and event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead Not sure what it means...

Comment: @Ben, `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tabs' ` means your __jquery-ui__ is not loading properly. You can try with `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` if it works then provide correct path of jquery ui

Comment: @Satpal worked thank you!, can you please explain, I thought I had the newer jquery-ui-1.10.4.js and it works with 1.9.1, am I reading it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your jquery and UI liberary not compatible. Both should be updated version.

To figure out, just replace your existing ui library with jquery ui 1.9.1 version from cdn.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**However, you should use both updated version.**

**Update**

You can see your code working fine here.
http://jsfiddle.net/Gay2V/

Comment: still nothing, I thought I am using v1.10.4, its older then 1.9.1?

Comment: Okay. Add jquery library from cdn too. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 I see no problem with your code, this is why I'm looking at version first.

Comment: thankyou worked!  can you please explain, I thought I had the newer version jquery-ui-1.10.4.js and it works with 1.9.1, so 1.9.1 is newer then 1.10.4?

Comment: No, 1.9.1 is older than 1.10.4. But what you did wrong is jquery library was older but UI was newer. you can see here different version http://jquery.com/download/ and for UI http://code.jquery.com/ui/

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Create An Account</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
     @Html.Partial("_Login", Model.LoginModel)
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
      @Html.Partial("_Register", Model.RegisterModel)

</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
</script>
```

Model:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public LoginViewModel LoginModel { get; set; }

    public RegisterViewModel RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action for MainView:

```
 public ActionResult MainView()
    {

        MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel
        {
            LoginModel = new LoginViewModel(),
            RegisterModel = new RegisterViewModel()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```